# Performance problem with labels on query layer in ArcMap 10.7

Tags: arcmap, labeling, query-layer

I have a project in ArcMap 10.7.
In this project I defined a query layer that join a polygon feature class (SDE) with an Oracle view (non spatial).
For each polygon I have many (7) records in the joined view.
The query layer is time enabled.
All works fine if don't label polygons.
When labelling is activated redrawing becomes very slow (from 1 second without labels to 55 seconds with labels).
Labels are very simple, just one field.
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: QueryLayers aren't likely to be faster than the view.  It's been ages since I last tuned an Oracle view, but then general process remains the same with respect to query structure, indexes and explain plan. You haven't provided any details on the problem, so there aren't many suggestions which could be offered.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, I'll try to better explain the problem.
We have two Oracle databases on two different servers. The first one collect chronological data, the second is an SDE geodatabase connected to the first via database link.
We need to create time aware services using query layers that join featueclass and chronological data.
We created the map service but it is too slow.
After some tests we realized the bottleneck is the network connection between the db servers.
We solved the problem using a materialized view on the geodb side.

Comment: It's pretty much always a *design error* to place the spatial data in a database separate from the other core data. Literally every project I've worked on that did not correct this failed (e.g., stop work after initial design review). Materialized view is okay, but live join to  real-time data is better.

Comment: Thank you Vince, I really appreciate your suggestions and I agree this is a design problem, but I can't make any changes now. It must also be said that in this case time is not a critical factor, data will be updated with a weekly frequency and I have to store just the last week and only one measure for each day.